# what is jruby and how it is related to javascript

Tags: javascript, jruby

I am a Javascript developer. At my new job place they told me to study jruby and ext-js. It is all clear with ext-js. But I have done some web search on jruby and got confused. How jruby is related to javascript? How should I start learning it? Where can I find some tutorial on it? Thanks for help.

Comment: I have already did it and didn't get answers I need. I am interested on the part how it is related to javascript.

Comment: Well, if "[JRuby is a 100% *Java* implementation of the Ruby programming language](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/AboutJRuby)", then JRuby is related to "javascript" as much as Ruby and Java are related to "javascript". Do you really need this community to connect the dots for you? BTW, [there is no "javascript"](http://PointedEars.de/es-matrix), which you should already know.

Comment: @PointedEars I don't think this is a completely bogus question; I would think that one _would_ be confused if they saw articles on JRuby and didn't see anything about Javascript. Where might he come then? Why, here!

Comment: @Jwosty Then they had misunderstood Stack Overflow, which is not a replacement for own research (which is really just a Google input box away here). And since when does a "J" prefix indicate "JavaScript"? Avoid the jQuery fanboys. (Which part of "There is no 'javascript'" did you not understand?)

Comment: @PointedEars Yes, I see you do have a point

Comment: @PointedEars Calm down. I don`t say "J" prefix indicates "Javascript". And I know that javascript is an implementation of Ecmascript.

Comment: @RafaelSedrakyan Sigh. [psf 10.1]

Comment: It's **not** related to JavaScript, at all, in any way. Why in the world did you think it was? Google would have told you this quicker than asking this question.

Comment: In all humor: President Thomas 'Tug' Benson of Hot Shots! Part Deux would say - if "There is no javascript" then rename something to javascript. Do I have to think of everything? http://imdb.to/TMxgb8 http://bit.ly/YWpxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java + Ruby = Jruby . JRuby is a ruby implementation of the Ruby programming language that runs on jvm. read this book -> [introduction to jruby](http://javasymposium.techtarget.com/html/images/NFord_Intro_JRuby.pdf) you will understand what jruby is and some basic examples.

Answer (score 2):

JRuby is not at all related to Javascript; it is a version of Ruby on the JVM -- so it is tightly integrated with Java: in fact, JRuby is even written entirely in said language.

Some people get Java and Java*script* confused: the former is a popular statically typed language influenced much by C++, while the latter is a web client language that is run in the browser. They are not related, so JRuby has no more to do with it than Ruby does.

> JRuby is a Java implementation of the Ruby programming language. ... JRuby is tightly integrated with Java to allow the embedding of the interpreter into any Java application with full two-way access between the Java and the Ruby code (similar to Jython for the Python language). —*Wikipedia*

Answer (score 1):

JRuby is a implementation of ruby that runs on the JVM.  Ruby and Javascript are both programming languages.    Beyond that, there is not much of a relationship.

Best to ask your boss why.  Maybe they want you to move into server side scripting, where (J)ruby is quite common.